# Assigning a swift closure (block equivalent) to an existing objective-c block being accessed using a bridge

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-blocks

I am using Swift and was wondering if there's a way I can assign a closure to an existing objective-c block.

```
fromObjC?.performBlock = {someVar in /*do something*/}
```

It gives me an error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression".

Comment: Yes there is a way, but the types need to match. What type is performBlock?

Comment: **bold** `void(^performBlock)( UIStoryboardSegue* segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc )`

Comment: You can't assign to the result of optional chaining.  The easiest way around it would be to use `if let p = fromObjC { p.performBlock = ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All pointers to objects in objective-C must be Optional in swift because a pointer can be nil. If you know that the variable will never actually be nil, you should use Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals (`TypeName!`) so that you don't have to unwrap it.

So

```
void(^performBlock)( UIStoryboardSegue* segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc )
```

becomes:

```
{(segue : UIStoryboardSegue!, svc : UIViewController!, dvc : UIViewController!) in
    // Implementation
}
```

If the variable might be nil, you should use a normal Optional which would look like this:

```
{(segue : UIStoryboardSegue?, svc : UIViewController?, dvc : UIViewController?) in
    // Implementation
}
```

And actually, if you are assigning it to that property, you don't even have to specify the types (they are inferred):

```
{(segue, svc, dvc) in
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: Hey @drewag, I found out what was wrong. Everything is good including my format of the types. It was **fromObjC?.performBlock**, it should be **fromObjC!.performBlock**. Thanks!

Comment: So, why do you have to add that "in" word there? {(segue, svc, dvc) in }

Comment: @zumzum that is just the syntax of the language. It signifies the end it the parameter list and the beginning of the implementation