# Objective-C method that returns a block is not available in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, objective-c-blocks

I'm building an Objective-C library that must be compatible with Swift, and I'm having an issue with several methods that return Objective-C blocks being unavailable in Swift even though the interface is being generated in Swift.

An example of a method that has this issue is:

```
+ (SDLLogFilterBlock)filterByDisallowingString:(NSString *)string caseSensitive:(BOOL)caseSensitive;
```

which is being generated in Swift as:

```
open class func filter(byDisallowingString string: String, caseSensitive: Bool) -> __ObjC.SDLLogFilterBlock
```

`SDLLogFilterBlock` is defined as:

```
typedef BOOL (^SDLLogFilterBlock)(SDLLogModel *log);
```

which is being generated in Swift as:

```
public typealias SDLLogFilterBlock = (SDLLogModel) -> Bool
```

When I'm attempting to use the `SDLLogFilter` class in Swift, however, there is no autocompletion appearing for any method like this and attempting to write it out manually tells me that this method does not exist.

Does Swift 3 not work with generated methods that return a block?

Comment: Can you give an example of code in the `SDLLogFilter` that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Did you add Bridging Header file to your Swift project for your Objective-C library?

Comment: @BallpointBen Attempting to use the `SDLLogFilter` class methods themselves don't work. There is no autocomplete, and manually attempting to fill out the method (for example, the `filter` method above) says it cannot find the method.

Comment: @abdullahselek All other classes and methods in my library that I expect to work (there are a few variadric argument methods that I don't expect to work and do not appear in the generated interface) do work just fine.

Comment: Does this provide any insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236755/assigning-a-swift-closure-block-equivalent-to-an-existing-objective-c-block-be

Comment: @BallpointBen No, it appears unrelated. I wrapped the Obj-C code in `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL` tags, so there won't be any optionals there.